# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, httpwebrequest

I have created application to calling API,
with some requirements just like apikey, username.
but I get this error

> **The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request**

Below is my code

```
public void Send(string method, string uri)
{
    var nonce = GetRandomString(32);
    var timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
    var passwordDigest = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Sha1(nonce + timestamp + secret)));
    var authHeader = String.Format("Username=\"{0}\", PasswordDigest=\"{1}\", Nonce=\"{2}\", Created=\"{3}\"  Content-type: application/json;charset=\"utf-8\"", key, passwordDigest, nonce, timestamp);

    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    httpRequest.Method = method;
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-WSSE: USERNAME " + authHeader);

    if (method.Equals("POST"))
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var data = new
            {
                name = "testing",
                key_id = "3",
                external_ids = external_ids
            };
            var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            httpRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse tResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What API are you hitting? You are most likely just formatting the authentication piece wrong

Comment: what api ?, I used hitt the rest api

Comment: You are hitting a URI which belongs to a specific API. That API is what is giving you the error. If we don't know what that API expects, we can't help you

Comment: https://api.emarsys.net/api/v2/contactlist this my API to hitt

Comment: Thanks. I found the docs: https://help.emarsys.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004521774-API-Authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, the following line:

```
httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-WSSE: USERNAME " + authHeader);
```

should be:

```
httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-WSSE: UsernameToken " + authHeader);
```

It seems you copy and pasted incorrectly or something.